# How to add input text and button , inside option menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how could I add an input text box inside the select option drop menu. plzzz can anyone could solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better check the datalist element.

```
<input type="text" name="mytext" list="myList">
<datalist id="myList">
  <option value="Apple">  
  <option value="Banana">
</datalist>
```

Comment: no not like that the input box will be in the option list not in the select box

Comment: So you have to make custom select box. Slandered select box does not provide that functionality.